# What actions of prophet confirm affirmation from prophet?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

A companion prayed 2 units **AFTER** fajr jamaat before sunrise. this is reported  by Abu Dawood, where it says, “and the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) remained silent.” And ‘Ata’ ibn Abi Rabaah narrated that a man of the Ansaar said: “He did not say anything to him.” Al-‘Iraaqi said: its isnaad is hasan. And a version narrated by Ibn Abi Shaybah says: “He did not tell him to do that or tell him not to do it.” And a version narrated by Ibn Hibbaan says: “he did not denounce him.” The reports explain one another.

This silence is taken as affirmation in uloom ul hadith.

The smile of prophet is also taken as affirmation. This information is based on Allahs fingers text given by a jewish woman to aisha and the prophet smiled.

Based on above information i Searched in a internet search engine and failed to find answers.

In a discussion, 2 people were discussing buraq and flying horses. And it was metioned sulayman had flying horses and buraq is neither a horse nor does it fly. Then hadith of prophet laughing such that his molar were visible when aisha said sulayman had flying horses was mentioned.

A third person who read the above hadith said laughing negates flying horses of sulayman.

Hence the question arose which actions of prophet say his affirmation?

Answer (score 1):

Asalaam Alaikum

the science of hadith (uloom ul hadith) is a very vast subject. to completely understand a hadith one has to know the tafsir (commentary) of the hadith. i will try to clarify your question about what actions give affirmation.

after discussing the definitions of hadith by Ibn Hajr, 'Ali al-Qari al-Harawiy, Muhammad
Jamaluddin al-Qasimiy and Muhammad' Ajjaj al-Khatib, Abdullah (1986) concludes that the
meaning of the Hadith in terminology is:

"Whatever is attributed to Prophet Muhammad from the words (qauliyat),
actions (fi'liyat), silent approval (taqrir) or nature of either the nature of the
incident or the nature of the act, history of either before or after becoming
the Messenger" (Abdullah 1986 : 2-3; Qattan 1987: 7)

so we can see that all the major scholars of hadith have agreed upon the three principles.

01- words (including interview and questionnaires)

02- actions (including participant observation and non-participant observation)

03- silent approval (including indirect consent)

for a basic understanding this much will be enough, insha Allah.

and about the last part of your question about two people talking about flying horses, can you please provide a reference.

may Allah the mighty and sublime grant you mercy and guide you to the straight path.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Prophet said, “O Aisha, what is this?” Aisha said, “My dolls.” Among them was a horse with wings made of rags, so the Prophet said, “What is this I see?” Aisha said, “A horse,” The Prophet said, “What is this on it?” Aisha said, “Two wings.” The Prophet said, “A horse with two wings?” Aisha said, “Have you not heard that Solomon had horses with two wings?” The Prophet laughed so deeply that his molar teeth could be seen.

Source: Sunan Abī Dāwūd 4932

Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to Al-Albani

Comment: how can you still say that laughing in that incident negates anything?. do you have any evidence or proof for that claim.

Comment: Bro, i didnt say that. It was another person. I accept sulayman had flying horses